# Can't send mail but receive is fine AWS and Vestacp

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, smtp, exim, vesta

I've been looking for my problem in Vesta Forum. I found some information, but still sending mail doesn't work.

1. My IP isn't on any black list
2. I turned Off `ipv6`, `spamassasin` and `clamd` in exim configuration like this:

   ```
   SPAMASSASSIN = no
   SPAM_SCORE = 50
   CLAMD =  no

   disable_ipv6=true
   ```

Mail are not sending from:

1. PHP mail() and Wordpress
2. Roundcube

In Roundcube I got following error, while sending to gmail:

> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> ***@gmail.com
>   host alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [108.177.14.26]
>   SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
>   550-5.7.1 [52.210.16.21       7] Our system has detected that this message is
>   550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
>   550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
>   550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError
>   550 5.7.1  for more information. b10si20481ljd.189 - gsmtp
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; bobcars.pl
>
> Action: failed
>   Final-Recipient: rfc822;***@gmail.com
>   Status: 5.0.0
>   Remote-MTA: dns; alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [52.210.16.21       7] Our system has detected that this message is
>   550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
>   550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
>   550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError
>   550 5.7.1  for more information. b10si20481ljd.189 - gsmtp

While I'm sending to another (polish o2.pl)

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  pzatorski@o2.pl
    all hosts for 'o2.pl' have been failing for a long time (and retry time not reached)
Reporting-MTA: dns; bobcars.pl

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;pzatorski@o2.pl
Status: 5.0.0
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to offical VestaCP forum i've noticed that you need to contact AWS to reduce your sending email limits.